# Trying to build a clickable index with PHP / Javascript that displays data for each item clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have spent a lot of time trawling the web for help on this, but I haven't found anything that does what I'm looking for and having tried to cobble together solutions from multiple sources, have basically run into a dead end.

What I'm trying to do is create a web page to list musicians on one part of the page so that I can click on the name of an individual musician and load a list of their albums, songs, lyrics, etc. on another part of the same page. The data is all in a MySQL database and each item in the database has a unique ID.

I can get the data out of the database and into an array and I can create a list of musicians and also a list of their info on a separate part of the page if I manually set a the ID. If I can get a click to return the ID I can then focus on trying to get my head around using Ajax to load the required data, and I guess JQuery to display it where I want it on the page, but I am stuck on getting the clickable list working.

I am using Joomla 3.1 to create the site but the code is just PHP and Javascript.

My most recent effort is as follows:

```
<ul id="nav" style="list-style:none">

<?php
    foreach ( $this->items as $item ) {
       echo '<li id='.$item->itemid.' onclick="$(this).index()" >'.$item->title.'</li>';
    }   
?> 
"</ul>" 

<script>
    linkClicked = function (index) {
       alert($('#nav li').get(index).id);
    }
```

Like all my other efforts this creates a nice list but nothing happens when I click on any of the listed items and I am clearly way off track.  I had intended that this would display an alert showing the id of the item selected, but no alert appears.  I have a feeling that the solution is pretty trivial but I am just not getting it and any help would be very gratefully received.

For anyone not familiar with Joomla, it provides functions that load MySQL data into an array, with individual items being accessed using the name of the relevant column from the database.  So $item->title gives the value of the 'title' field for the current row of data.

Comment: onclick='linkClicked(this)' ...  alert($(index).attr('id'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fire your code when the document is ready. your code is not triggered. You need to bind a click event to your li tags on document ready like so:

```
//on document ready
$(function(){
  //select the li tags from #nav and bind a click event to them
  $('#nav li').on('click', function(){
    //When li is clicked: alert the attribute "id" from the clicked element (this = li element)
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
  })
});
```

with delegation:works also for elements that are dynamical added to the dom (after the page has loaded, for example by an ajax call)

```
$(function(){
  $('#nav').on('click', 'li', function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'))
  })
});
```

Comment: Kasper, thanks for this.  I think sometimes I get so wrapped up in one way of looking at things that I just miss the obvious. It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: yeah bro, I know what you mean. You'll get used to it. pleased to help you!